# Parsing XML structure in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and my stored procedure takes a structured xml parameter with multiple levels like this.

```xml
DECLARE @XML_Account XML=
<Accounts>
    <Account>
        <NameID></NameID>
        <AID></AID>
        <TransactionTime></TransactionTime>
        <TransactionEndTime></TransactionEndTime>
        <TrasactionName></TrasactionName>
        <Purchases>
            <Purchase>
                <Name></Name>
                <Qty></Qty>
                <Cost></Cost>
                <Tax1></Tax1>
                <Tax2></Tax2>
                <Tax3></Tax3>
                <Tax4></Tax4>
            </Purchase>
           <Purchase>
                <Name></Name>
                <Qty></Qty>
                <Cost></Cost>
                <Tax1></Tax1>
                <Tax2></Tax2>
                <Tax3></Tax3>
                <Tax4></Tax4>
            </Purchase>
        </Purchases>
        <Error></Error>
    </Account>
</Accounts>
```

in which `Purchase` node can repeat at times. I want to store the XML above in atable. I tried this

```
select  a.b.value('Account[1]/NameID[1]','varchar(10)'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/AID[1]','varchar(10)'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/TransactionTime[1]','datetime'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/TransactionEndTime[1]','datetime'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/TrasactionName[1]','varchar(10)'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Name[1]','varchar(10)'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Qty[1]','int'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Cost[1]','Money'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Tax1[1]','Money'),
        a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Tax2[1]','Money'),
    a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Tax3[1]','Money'),
    a.b.value('Account[1]/Purchases[1]/Purchase[1]/Tax4[1]','Money')
    from @XML_Account.nodes('Accounts') a(b)
```

But I get only one purchase node at time. I want all the purchase nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First shred on `/Accounts/Account` to get one row for each account and then in a cross apply you shred on `Purchases/Purchase` to get one row for each purchase.

```sql
select A.X.value('(NameID/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       A.X.value('(AID/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       A.X.value('(TransactionTime/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
       A.X.value('(TransactionEndTime/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
       A.X.value('(TrasactionName/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       P.X.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
       P.X.value('(Qty/text())[1]', 'int'),
       P.X.value('(Cost/text())[1]', 'money'),
       P.X.value('(Tax1/text())[1]', 'money'),
       P.X.value('(Tax2/text())[1]', 'money'),
       P.X.value('(Tax3/text())[1]', 'money'),
       P.X.value('(Tax4/text())[1]', 'money')
from @XML_Account.nodes('/Accounts/Account') as A(X)
  cross apply A.X.nodes('Purchases/Purchase') as P(X)
```